# different url in different browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

I'm using asp.net mvc. I made a link using `Html.ActionLink` chrome and Firefox shows me an seo friendly url like this:

> http://localhost:3267/Store/Browse?category=آموزش-برنامه-نویسی

but IE 9.0 shows me something like this:

> http://localhost:3267/Store/Browse?category=%D8%A7%D9%93%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87-%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C

What should I do in order to show friendly seo url also in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Those hexadecimal characters -- the ones that start with the % sign -- are the characters in the string, encoded for the URL. As far as a search engine is concerned, they are the same characters.

Comment: the users are far more important than search engines and i dont know why just IE shows something like this and not the other browsers,

Comment: Fair enough. You might want to update your question to reflect that the users are more important than the search engine.